# Creating new records and their hasMany children?

Tags: ember.js

So, I have a hasMany/belongsTo relationship set up between three models:

- App.Character
- App.Skill
- App.Rank

Here's the gist:

```
App.Character = DS.Model.extend({
    skills: DS.hasMany('App.Rank')
});

App.Rank = DS.Model.extend({
    rank: DS.attr('number'),
    skill: DS.belongsTo('App.Skill'),
    character: DS.belongsTo('App.Character', {inverse: 'skills'}) //I've got a few properties in App.Character tied to this one, actually. Hence the need for "inverse"
});

App.Skill = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    rank: DS.hasMany('App.Rank')
});
```

Basically, I have a list of skills that are static. Each character has a rank in each skill. This works out alright with my fixture data, but I'm not sure how to populate rank data for new records in App.Character (that is, when I use App.Characters.createRecord()).

I'm populating all of the other default data on createRecord() right now, but I have no clue how to add new entries in App.Rank when I create a character (or how to make sure a new one gets added for each skill).

Basically, when I create a new Character record, I'd like to have it look at all of the Skill records, create a new Rank record for each one, associated to the new Character record.

Does this make sense?

So my question is: How can I create new associated records in hasMany child fields for a record?